# Dynamic array not behaving as expected

Tags: python, iteration, dynamic-arrays

Replacing words/phrases in larger project. I can do it first time around. But when attempting to build on the changed line I have an issue with the dynamic array `listings[]`
Summarizing the issue. Here is some basic Python:

```
# concurrentTest.py

import re

subString = [' string1',' string2',' string3']
word = ['new_word1', 'new_word2', 'new_word3']
lineString = ['This line, needs new_word','This line, needs new_word', 'This line, needs new_word']

# matches word with underscore
wordsRegex = "(\S+_\S+[a-z])"
# matches word ending in comma
stringRegex = "(\s[a-z]+,)"

# store results
listings = []

# make the first change to our line string with a new word for each line
for (x, y) in zip(subString, lineString):
    listings = re.sub(stringRegex, x, y)
    # print(listings)               # This shows that listings have been changed with a string number 'This string1 needs a new_word'

# try to make the second change to give 'This string1 needs a new_word1' etc
for (x, y) in zip(word, listings):
    listings = re.sub(wordsRegex, x, y)
    # print(listings)                 # If listings is declared [] like lineString why just first 3 letters 'Thi' printed?
```

Comment: `re.sub()` returns a string. So after the loop, `listings` contains the result of the last `re.sub()`. I think you want to use `listings.append(re.sub(...))`

Comment: BTW, Python calls dynamic arrays lists.

Comment: Yes, the first time you do `listings = re.sub(...)`, you entirely invalidate `listing = []`. It's as if it never happened. `=` replaces what object the name on the left is referring to; it doesn't actually affect the object itself.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I get that. But I get `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`  for `listings(re.sub(stringRegex, x, y))`

Comment: You're missing `.append` in there if you're going with Barmar's suggestion.

Comment: True. Thank you. I was trying to call the list as a function. Forgetting that its adding an item to the end of the list